# LinearLayout even distribution

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am having trouble distributing three buttons inside a horizontal Layout.

This is my XML code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fab_btn_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_separator_2">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_cancel_trip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:fabCustomSize="70dp"
        app:maxImageSize="30dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fab_cancel">

    </com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_active_trips"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:fabCustomSize="70dp"
        app:maxImageSize="30dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_active_trips">

    </com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_chat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:fabCustomSize="70dp"
        app:maxImageSize="30dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fab_chat" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Does this have anything to do with the fact that this are fab (FloatingActionButtons)?

Thank you.

Comment: Does the buttons overlap? Does the buttons go out of the screen? Does the buttons are not aligned? What is the problem?

Comment: All buttons are aligned on the left. One after the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide LinearLayout a gravity of centre or Use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are three FABs, and you have given `android:layout_weight="1"` on every FAB, you need to give a weightsum of 3 in the linear layout in which they are present.
Like:
`android:weightSum="3"`

Your final code would look like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fab_btn_layout"
    android:weightSum="3" <!-- Here you want to add the line" -->
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_separator_2">
    
    <!-- your 3 FAB here -->
    ........
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

```
       <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/fab_btn_layout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_margin="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_separator_2">

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_cancel_trip"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:fabCustomSize="70dp"
    app:maxImageSize="30dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fab_cancel">

</com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_active_trips"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:fabCustomSize="70dp"
    app:maxImageSize="30dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_active_trips">

</com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_chat"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:fabCustomSize="70dp"
    app:maxImageSize="30dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fab_chat" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code -

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/fab_btn_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_cancel_trip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:fabCustomSize="70dp"
        app:maxImageSize="30dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_active_trips"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:fabCustomSize="70dp"
        app:maxImageSize="30dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_find"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_chat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:fabCustomSize="70dp"
        app:maxImageSize="30dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_sort" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Above code you give you this result

[image]

Change `app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_fab_icon"` in all three FAB.

Happy Coding !

Answer (score 0):

So I finally got the three buttons evenly distributed by adding  android:gravity="center" -Thanks NanPd- to the LinearLayout and adding two spaces between the buttons. I am not sure if this is the best approach but got the result I wanted.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fab_btn_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/layout_padding"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_separator_2">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_cancel_trip"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:fabCustomSize="70dp"
        app:maxImageSize="30dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fab_cancel"/>
    
    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"/>
    
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_active_trips"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:fabCustomSize="70dp"
        app:maxImageSize="30dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_active_trips"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_chat"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:fabCustomSize="70dp"
        app:maxImageSize="30dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fab_chat"/>

</LinearLayout>
```